# telneting to ssh port works, but SSH not

Tags: ssh, networking, routing

I have a two network interfaces machine, one is connected to the router and gets an automatic address via DHCP. The other has a static IP in a different subnet. I can ping both IP addresses, telnet to port 22 and see the "SSH prompt".. just fine. (trying them with switching the cable in my notebook)

**Question:** but when it comes to connecting to this machine via SSH I can only connect through the NIC that is connected via the router, not directly. It just timeouts when I try to connect directly. Why?

The firewall rules are the default, tried rebooting both sides, I only modified the "UseDNS to no" in the `sshd_config` on the machine.

Comment: What happens if you nmap the port where ssh hangs?

Comment: On which interface does your ssh daemon listen? Check config with `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Listen` and check running daemon with `netstat -putan | grep ssh`.

Comment: What's the output of `ssh -v user@domain` (you might need to be prepared to supply more detailed log `ssh -vv` or `-vvv` if need be). You might also want to run `sshd -d` (`-ddd`) on the server on an alternative port, try connecting to that and then looking at the log from the SSH daemon.

Comment: @chaos if he gets SSH prompt, `sshd` is probably listening on that device as well.

Comment: First things first: are you sure you're connecting to the right machine (no alias in `.ssh/config`, no protocol-aware router in the middle)? If you are, then post the output of `ssh -vv`.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If not, would you post the output of ssh -vv as others have asked for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure you have a route problem. Probably you either have none or two default routes.

Let's assume you have two networks, *192.168.0.0/24* and *192.168.1.0/24*, your router's IP *192.168.0.1* and your machine's addresses *192.168.0.2* and *192.168.1.2*. A manual configuration would be something like:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1
sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Although each scenario would require a slightly different command. [[1]](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-route-add/)

Please make sure there's no other default route. Also, make sure you have `ipv4_forward` set to 1. [[2]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding)