# WLAN connected but no internet access

Tags: wifi, iptables, ethernet, ifconfig, wlan

I have a linux box and has ethernet, wlan STA/client and wlan Access Point.
It's a internet connection via ethernet and I can log in to the box via ssh. But I wish to use the box like a wireless router and be able to connect to internet by using for example a smart phone. I can connect my phone to wifi but it has no internet access.

Here are my interfaces:

`eth0` is Ethernet
`eth1` and `eth2` is WLAN

```
# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:BC:22:17:20
          inet addr:10.10.1.116  Bcast:10.10.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:bcff:fe22:1720/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6377 errors:0 dropped:608 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:865911 (845.6 KiB)  TX bytes:59751 (58.3 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:BC:22:17:20
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:bcff:fe22:1720/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6417 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:623 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:985364 (962.2 KiB)  TX bytes:60399 (58.9 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:BC:22:17:21
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:15:BC:22:17:21
          inet addr:192.168.2.10  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::15:bcff:fe22:1721/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:502 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:44998 (43.9 KiB)  TX bytes:24874 (24.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:13525 (13.2 KiB)  TX bytes:13525 (13.2 Ki
```

B)

And here is `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet dhcp

iface eth2 inet dhcp

iface br0 inet dhcp
hostname gw-143A
   bridged_ports  eth0
```

Wireless:

```
# iwconfig
tap0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

br0       no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11-bgn  Mode:Master  Frequency:2.457 GHz

eth1      IEEE 802.11-bgn  ESSID:""
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:9F64-0D78-CCAB-A8 [3]
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

sit0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your linux box to act as a WLAN access point, you will need to:

- make sure your wireless NICs use a [driver which supports AP](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers). Output of `lsmod | grep 80211` usually helps. If your driver doesn't support AP mode, you'll have to get a new WLAN adapter which does.
- make sure your kernels supports [IP forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding) and enable it. This is usually done by running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` as root.
- configure routing tables to forward network packets from `br0` to `eth2`:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE`

`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o br0 -j ACCEPT`

- install and configure an [access point management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd).
- configure a DHCP server which would assign your phone an IP address, if this is not already done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried just as you have described. But still not succeeded. I forgot to mention that I run the buildroot.

Comment: It works now. I have changed DNS to 8.8.8.8 on my phone. Thanks again

Comment: @pomegranatex Good. Thanks for reporting back!