# What is kernel ip forwarding? related question

Tags: iptables, forwarding

This question is related to the answer & comment in [What is kernel ip forwarding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding)

from @LawrenceC

post1:

> So in the above example, if you have an internet connection on NIC 2,
>   you'd set NIC 2 as your default route and then any traffic coming in
>   from NIC 1 that isn't destined for something on 192.168.2.0/24 will go
>   through NIC 2.

and also post2:

> the internet-facing interface (NIC 1 per above) needs a MASQUERADE
>   rule in iptables's POSTROUTING on a chain to do that. See
>   [revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html)

At http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html it says:

> Then you'll need to configure iptables to forward the packets from
>   your internal network, on /dev/eth1, to your external network on
>   /dev/eth0.
>
> ```
> /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
> /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
> ```

Why I'd use `FORWARD` (according to *post2*) if the forward is already done by only setting `ip_forward` (according to *post1*):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Setting `ip_forward` allows the network stack to forward packets from one interface to another.  You do not need any additional packet filtering or routing specified if all you want is for packets to be forwarded from one locally attached network to another locally attached network.  However, if you want to specify routes (other than default) to specific remote networks, or to perform other packet rewriting (nat, in the example above), you will need to specify more than just the `ip_forward` sysctl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `ip_forward` allows packet forwarding *in general*. Some Linux distributions may disallow forwarded packets in `iptables` for security reasons, e.g. if `ip_forward` is set by error.

```
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

sets a rule to allow packets from `eth0` to `eth1` that are responses or similary related packets to an already established connection.

```
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

sets an explicit rule to allow packets from `eth1` to `eth0`.

This allows clients from `eth1` to access servers behind `eth0` regardless of the default `iptables` configuration.

Comment: loved your answer here! I also had a question regarding iptables which I was wondering if you might know the reasoning behind: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359884/understanding-an-iptables-shell-script