# Why is ip_forward disabled by default? Any side effects if enabled?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I need to forward an interface and I wonder why it is disabled by default.

Will there be security issues or side effects when I enable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ip_forward` is only useful on multihomed systems (i.e. more than one network interface) and makes routing of network packets between those interfaces possible. By enabling `ip_forward` your box essentially becomes a router.

Routing is an optional network function and as such disabled by default.

As for the downside/possible risks: when one of those interfaces is facing a public subnet (WAN/internet or possible hostile LAN), routing makes attacks possible. That's why you need to address those potential security issues with a firewall.

There is an excellent answer at [What is kernel ip forwarding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding) with more information on the subject.