# Routing between two machines

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I intend to pass Internet from openSUSE Leap 15.1 to CentOS 7:

- openSUSE Leap 15.1 machine with access to Internet through a wireless router
- CentOS 7 machine without access to Internet due to lack of proper wireless chip driver

I connect openSUSE machine to CentOS by an Ethernet cable. My understanding is that I should have two different sub-nets:

- openSUSE

  - Has static IP address of `192.168.2.252/24`
  - Has DHCP IP address of `192.168.1.51/24`

    - Access to Internet through `192.168.1.1`
- CentOS

  - Has static IP address of `192.168.2.251/24`

#### Observations

- Inside CentOS `192.168.2.251` I can ping openSUSE `192.168.2.252`
- Inside CentOS `192.168.2.251` I can ping openSUSE `192.168.1.51`
- Inside CentOS `192.168.2.251` I can **not** ping internet router `192.168.1.1`
- Inside CentOS `192.168.2.251` I can **not** ping `1.1.1.1`
- Inside CEntOS `192.168.2.251` I do **not** have access to Internet

#### Routing on openSUSE

```
> ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.51 metric 600 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.252 metric 100
```

#### Question

I cannot figure out what is wrong with routing. It's strange that from CentOS I can ping openSUSE on both sub-nets, but I cannot ping internet router!

Comment: You want openSUSE to act as a router. This requires it to forward traffic that is not destined to itself. Most Linux distros are configured to ignore such traffic. Ensure that [IP forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding) is enabled. Use `sysctl` to enable it permanently.

Comment: @berndbausch When I check with `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` I'm getting `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. I think IP forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Yes it is. A different thought: What's the routing table on Centos?

Comment: @berndbausch CentOS `ip route` output summary is `default via 192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.2.0/24 src 192.168.2.251`

Comment: That's the problem. There is no connectivity to the default router. Make 192.168.2.252 the default. I don't understand the rest of your routing table; can't you just add `ip route` to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your internet router does not know about the network 192.168.2.0/24. The openSUSE machine knows that network and therefore answers even when accessed with the other address.

If you have access to the internet router and the address 192.168.1.51 is a fixed DHCP lease, you could add a route at the internet router pointing to 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.51.

A probably easier way would be to add masquerading to the wifi interface of the openSUSE machine like in this [question at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1633155/share-wifi-connection-with-ethernet/1633252#1633252).